# wordpress functions in function.php not being called from a template file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a child theme and recently installed woocommerce.

I have added a sidebar-shop.php file to template, which works fine when I put dummy content into it.

In my functions file I have:

```
function lls_woo_before_widget(){
    $content='<aside class="rightHandColumn">';
    return $content;
}
add_action('init','lls_woo_before_widget');
```

and in sidebar-shop.php I have:

```
lls_woo_before_widget();

dynamic_sidebar('secondary-aside');
```

The function lls_woo_before_widget doesn't seem to work but the sidebar comes in fine.

Why can't I use the function from within sidebar-shop.php and how can I (I know I could just write the code into the sidebar-shop.php file...)

Thanks

Comment: Use echo lls_woo_before_widget(); Just returning the content does not display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal here is to wrap the `secondary-aside` sidebar in an `<aside>` tag, you should be able to do this directly in the `sidebar-shop.php` file like this:

```
?>
<aside class="rightHandColumn">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar('secondary-aside'); ?>
</aside>
<?php
```

As for the errors you mentioned above:

- `init` is way too early to be calling this function, `init` hooks shouldn't generate any output since the [headers haven't been sent yet](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init), and `init` hooks don't modify `the_content`.
- `the_content` is used to output posts in the loop, and won't end up in the sidebar as you expect.
- `dynamic_sidebar()` [prints the sidebar markup](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar). If you wanted to act on the widgets in this sidebar as they are rendered, it [has hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/106476/wordpress-apply-filter-hook-to-a-particular-sidebar-widgets)
- If you want to call a php function from one file in another php file, you need to `include` the file that contains the function before you attempt to call it.

Comment: Thanks cpilko. I suppose I was just thinking i could use the functions. But I'll just write it out as you suggest.